# SQLite LeftJoin

Tags: sql, sqlite

With this query I get the data from two tables. Unfortunately, if the "Table2" there are no records, are not extracted even those of the "Table 1". How can I get the data of the "Table 1" even if the "Table2" does not have the corresponding data?

```
String tabella_conti = "SELECT a._id, " +
    "a.CAMPO1, " +
    "a.CAMPO2, " +
    "a.CAMPO3, " +
    "SUM(b.ZAMPO1) - SUM(b.ZAMPO2), " +         
    "b.ZAMPO3 " +       
    "FROM Table1 a LEFT JOIN MyTable b ON (a.CAMPO1  =  ZAMPO3) WHERE "+MyTable.DATA+ " <=? GROUP BY a.CAMPO1";
```

Comment: what contains `MyTable.DATA` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the where clause part of the join clause by replacing it with AND

```
SELECT (...)
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b
ON a.CAMPO1  =  ZAMPO3
AND (...)
GROUP BY (...)
```

This ensures that no rows from table1 will be excluded.